# Obligation to stand while praying on public access transportation

Tags: halacha, tefilla, minyan, travel, vehicles-transportation

According to [the answers to this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3233/praying-on-an-airplane) one doesn’t have to stand while praying on an airplane.

My question is, what is the Halacha regarding standing on a thing of public access transportation and vehicles such as subways/trollies/buses?

Comment: The principles are the same regardless of the mode of transportation. It depends on whether you can stand safely without being disrupted or causing disruption.

Comment: The mishna says "boat or wagon" -- it's whatever situation in which standing would be unsafe, or severely mess up your concentration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peninei Halakha ([Laws of Prayers 17:16](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/02-17-16/)) writes

> **When traveling by bus or train [...] if one can stand and concentrate properly, it is better that he stand for Shemoneh Esrei.
> However, if standing will disturb his kavanah, he must sit** with his
> feet together, stand when he needs to bow down, and then sit again. At
> the end of his prayer, he stands and takes three steps backwards.

(see further for additional situations, e.g., whether to pray on a bus when there is still time afterwards, and whether to do this regularly).

Note that, in all cases, a Jew should be mindful of *hilul Hashem*, in this case one should not disturb other passengers through his religious behavior. Safety is another concern that might lead someone to pray while sitting.